# Output from *++p and ++*p pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I don't understand why I am getting the output 1, 2, 3 for the below code. I believe it should be 1, 2, 2. What is the reason for the first output?

Also, let me point out that there are other questions that pertain to this kind of pointer arithmetic and dereferencing, but the answers to those questions suggest that the output should be 1, 2, 2.

```
int main()
{
    int p[3] = {1,2,3};
    int *q = p;
    printf("%d\n", *q);
    printf("%d\n", *++q);
    int x = ++*q;
    printf("%d\n", *q);
}
```

Comment: A couple of good answers already here. As a way to think about this, you could try initialising `p[]` to `{1, 2, 999}`: the output will still be `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: Or here's another thought: can you put brackets into `*++q` and `++*q` so that they do something which would give you `1, 2, 2` as the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int p[3] = {1,2,3};
int *q = p;
printf("%d\n", *q);
```

`q` points to the 1. element, the above prints 1

```
printf("%d\n", *++q);
```

`q` points to the 2. element, the above prints 2.

```
int x = ++*q;
```

The 2. element is incremented from 2 to 3.

```
printf("%d\n", *q);
```

`q` points to the 2. element, the above prints 3.

Comment: Very straightforward answer here, but you might want to explain, for a more general audience, why `*++q` results in 2, since `*q++` would have resulted in 1.

Comment: since *++q is having pre-increment operator it will result in 2,wherever in *q++ it will increment after execution of this statement

Answer (score 1):

`*++q` is parsed as `*(++q)`; the result of `++q` (which is `q + 1`) is dereferenced, and as a side effect `q` is incremented,

`++*q` is parsed as `++(*q)`; the result of `*q` (which is `2`) is the operand of `++`, which yields `3`.  As a side effect, `*q` is incremented.

Remember that both postfix and prefix `++` have a *result* and a *side effect*' and that the side effect does not have to be applied immediately after the expression has been evaluated.  IOW,

```
a = b++ * ++c;
```

will be evaluated as

```
a = b * (c + 1);
```

but `b` and `c` don't have to be updated until the next sequence point.

Answer (score -1):

```
Hi,


         int p[3] = {1,2,3};
            int *q = p;
            printf("%d\n", *q); // The output for this line is 1
            printf("%d\n", *++q); // Pre Incrementing the 1 which becomes 2
            int x = ++*q;

     // Here we are making the x point to same location as q and then we are
    incrementing the location of the address q. Like q is pointing to the next location and so is the x.Hence the *q gives us 3 which is the value of the incremented location.



 printf("%d\n", *q);

Hope it is helpful
```

Comment: x = ++*q doesn't  increment the location. its increment the value of element 2